# 1:* (One to Many) relationship in DB means Left or Right Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-quicksight

In SQL Server, there are two tables with Cardinal set as 1:*, (One to Many). When I am using QuickSight it is asking for Left, Right, Inner or Outer Join.

Now what is meant by 1:* in QS? Is it Left join or Right join?

Comment: maybe you should first learn the diference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: The answer depends entirely on what kind of results you want: there are valid cases for using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, and `FULL OUTER JOIN` with all different types of multiplicities - that's why we can't tell you that (e.g. "`1:*` means you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`" - because it _might_ or it _might not_ depending on what your data actually represents).